# Is the order of operations guaranteed in a bulk update?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am sending `delete` and `index` requests to elasticsearch in bulk (the example is adapted [from the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)):

```
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

The sequence above is intended to first `delete` a possible document with `_id=1`, then `index` a new document with the same `_id=1`.

**Is the order of the actions guaranteed?** In other words, for the example above, can I be sure that the `delete` will not touch the document `index`ed afterwards (because the order would not be respected for a reason or another)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delete` operation is useless in this scenario, if you simply `index` a document with the same ID, it will automatically and implicitly delete/replace the previous document with the same ID.

So if document with ID=1 already exists, simply sending the below command will replace it (read delete and re-index it)

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

Comment: True, my example is oversimplified. In reality I already have in ES, say, 4 documents (with id 1, 2, 3, 4) and need to delete them first, then reindex a subset of these documents (say, id 2 and 4). This is why I want to know whether the sequence of operation will first purge all four documents, then reindex the next two.

Comment: Yes, the execution order is guaranteed. It would be a nightmare of race conditions otherwise.

Comment: @Val, I could not found this scenario in the elastic documentation.
How do you know that order is preserved?

Answer (score 1):

According to an Elastic Team Member:

> Elasticsearch is distributed and concurrent. We do not guarantee that requests are executed in the order they are received.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/are-bulk-index-operations-serialized/83770/6

Comment: Thanks. They discuss the case where two `_bulk` operations arrive in sequence. My problem was with several operations within one `_bulk`  request.